# How can I disable automatic Facebook photo sync?

Tags: sync, facebook

Device: XPeria P
Android: JB 4.1.1

I recently enabled automatic photo sync, but I could not remember how I did it. Now, all of my photos gets synchronized to Facebook, and my data/3G charge is skyrocketing as the photos are always get synced.

So, how can I disable this feature?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open the Facebook app and tap the top right ([*hamburger*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamburger_button)) menu item in your sidebar. Scroll to the bottom and select `Account > App Settings > Sync Photos`. Choose `Don't sync my photos`.

[Source](https://www.facebook.com/help/274634689307648).

Comment: Thanks for the response. But I do not have such an option in my facebook app. But i was able to do this by disconnecting my facebook account from the phone.